# I need to relock bootloader

Tags: bootloader

I was trying to unlock my phone, LG Aristo, so that I could sell it. I unlocked bootloader, and now I need to relock it. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The standard set of commands should work:

First of all make sure that your phone is all stock and there's no tampering or modification. Then:

```
fastboot oem lock-go
```